# Can't display the same PictureBox more than once

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

```
        Dictionary<int, PictureBox> aCollection;

        aCollection = new Dictionary<int, PictureBox>();

        aCollection.Add(333, new PictureBox
            {
                Name = "Alcoholism",
                Image = Resources.alcoholism,
                Size = new Size(22, 22),
                SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        });

        aCollection.Add(289, new PictureBox
        {
            Name = "Hypertension",
            Image = Resources.hypertension,
            Size = new Size(22, 22),
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        });

        PictureBox condition = aCollection[333]; //333 refers to alcoholism
        condition.Location = new Point(450, 155);
        displayForm.Controls.Add(condition);

        PictureBox another = aCollection[289]; //289 refers to hypertension
        another.Location = new Point(550, 155);
        displayForm.Controls.Add(another);
```

The code above renders the following output on Winform (note the icons):

[image: two icons]

However, if I switch both `PictureBox` to use the same icon, with the hopes of displaying the same icon **twice** i.e.

```
        PictureBox condition = aCollection[289]; //Hypertension
        condition.Location = new Point(450, 155);
        displayForm.Controls.Add(condition);

        PictureBox another = aCollection[289]; //Hypertension
        another.Location = new Point(550, 155);
        displayForm.Controls.Add(another);
```

I get only one icon output.

[image: one icon]

Could someone please advise where I have gone wrong? Thank you.

[Edit] - The following code also produce only one icon

```
    PictureBox condition = aCollection[289];
    condition.Location = new Point(450, 155);
    displayForm.Controls.Add(condition);

    PictureBox another = condition;
    another.Location = new Point(550, 155);
    displayForm.Controls.Add(another);
```

Comment: how about `PictureBox another = condition;` and rest would be as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `another = aCollection[289]` you are referencing the same object as when you set condition = to it.  So when you update the location of another you are changing the location of `aCollection[289]` (as well as `condition`)

You need to create 2 separate instances of objects to add 2 picture boxes.  Probably best to make an extension method to do a deep copy of the object and then add them to Controls.  Add this class:

```
public static class MyExtension
{
    public static PictureBox DeepCopy(this PictureBox pb)
    {
        return new PictureBox { Name = pb.Name, Image = pb.Image, Size = pb.Size, SizeMode = pb.SizeMode };
    }
}
```

And then add the picture boxes using:

```
    PictureBox condition = aCollection[289].DeepCopy(); //289 refers to hypertension
    condition.Location = new Point(450, 155);
    this.Controls.Add(condition);

    PictureBox another = aCollection[289].DeepCopy(); //289 refers to hypertension
    another.Location = new Point(550, 155);
    this.Controls.Add(another);
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, appreciate the thorough solution!

Answer (score 0):

The same PictureBox control can't be on more than one location at once, so a new one is needed.

```
PictureBox newPictureBox(Image image, int X, int Y) {
    return new PictureBox() {
        Image = image,
        Size = new Size(22, 22),
        Location = new Point(X, Y),
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    };
}
```

and then

```
displayForm.Controls.Add(newPictureBox(Resources.hypertension, 450, 155));
displayForm.Controls.Add(newPictureBox(Resources.hypertension, 550, 155));
```

Comment: That solves the problem, thank you very much.

Though it is pretty odd that VS is not throwing any error messages at all when the control is being used more than once.